# $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^{n-k}.$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk  x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk  x^{n-k}.$$

I want a deeper understanding of solving problems in this nature. I can´t grasp this writing way.I get confused just by looking at these problems. Please be patient with me. ;)

Comment: Maybe start with the definition of the binomial coefficient notation?

Comment: i dont know what to do with only one term. normally its a+b to power something

Comment: I did and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$${n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$$

Comment: I usually can´t expand the Summations to get to ur hint.

Comment: I finally managed to do it!thnks a lot!! how can i write a question mathematically without posting a picture?

Comment: You're welcome. For your question see the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The sum on right hand side (RHS) of the equation is the sum on the left hand side (LHS) of the equation written backwards. Let me explain:

By definition of the sum,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk  x^k = \binom n0 x^0 + \binom n1 x^1 \ \ + \ \ ... \ \ +   \binom {n}{n-1} x^{n-1}\ + \binom {n}{n} x^{n} \\
$$

writing the sum in reverse order to yeild,
$$
= \binom {n}{n} x^{n} + \binom {n}{n-1} x^{n-1} \ \ + \ \ ... \ \ + \binom n1 x^1 +\binom n0 x^0\\
$$

with a bit more work we have,

$$
= \binom {n}{n-0} x^{n-0} + \binom {n}{n-1} x^{n-1}\ \ + \ \ ... \ \ + \binom n{n-(n-1)} x^{n-(n-1)} +\binom n{n-n} x^{n-n}\\
$$

that is,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk  x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n{n-k}  x^{n-k}.
$$

Finally we note the following combinatorial identity,
$$
\begin{align}
& \binom nk = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-(n-k))!(n-k)!} = \binom n{n-k}
\end{align}
$$

Applying the combinatorial identity delivers the desired result,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk  x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk  x^{n-k}.
$$